# How to get get value of java script's variable from a website in c# .net

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I want to get value of JavaScript's variable from a website in c# net . Currently I use this code:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

string webData = wc.DownloadString("://87.126.167.13/");

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(webData);
```

It returns HTML. But I want the value of temperature from this link:
`://87.126.167.13/`   but it returns:

`<td>Temperature:</td><td><script>document.write(MNS,TW1,TW2,'.',TF,TF1)</script> C</td>`

Comment: instead of that particular link you can try its CSV output at http://87.126.167.13/x and then you can get the Soil temp and Air temp values for any date

Answer (score 0):

The CSV page format (`http://87.126.167.13/x`) that website has would probably be more useful to you. It looks like:

```
Date,AirTemp,SoilTemp,Humidity
2013-08-22 14:46:00,+31.20,+21.6,32
2013-08-22 15:13:55,+32.22,+21.5,31
** more values **
2013-08-22 13:50:26,+30.39,+21.6,34
2013-08-22 14:18:19,+31.40,+21.6,33
1004+2200
```

You could parse these values with some simple code, like

```
var lines = webData.Split('\n');
var allData = lines.Skip(1).Take(lines.Length - 2).Select(x => new WeatherData(x));
var latestDate = allData.Max(x => x.DateTime);
var latestAirTemp = allData.First(x => x.DateTime == latestDate).AirTemp;

public class WeatherData
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal AirTemp { get; set; }
    public decimal SoilTemp { get; set; }
    public int Humidity { get; set; }
    public WeatherData(string rawData)
    {
        // implement
    }
}
```

That or the script file `http://87.126.167.13/s`, which is what defines the `MNS,TW1,...` that you mention. From that, you could parse out what value(s) you want. It looks like:

```
var AN3=   10;var MNS="+";var TW1=    1;var TW2=    9;var TF=    7;var TF1=    0;var HR=   22;var MN=   23;var SC=   39;var DY=   22;var MH=    8;var YR=    3;var RH="   53";var WD="South-East";var WS="00";var MNS2="+";var ST="21.5";var BP="8261";var RAD2="1.11";
```